# how to display the output in the screen?

Tags: c#

I coded everything, when I run the project it's not showing the output on the screen. Can anybody tell me, what's the code used to display the output on the screen?

It is the code used in my (not console) application.

```
private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    StorageFile xmlFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("Content1.xml");
    XmlDocument xmlDoc;
    xmlDoc = await XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(xmlFile);
    System.Xml.Linq.XDocument duc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(xmlDoc.GetXml());

    var query=
        from Date in duc.Root.Elements("Serial")
        where Date.Attribute("No").Value=="1"
        from Current in Date.Elements("Current")
        select new {
            NarratedBy=Current.Attribute("NarratedBy").Value,
            value=Current.Attribute("Date").Value
        };

    foreach(var Date in query) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", Date.NarratedBy, Date.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to do an output to screen for it to show on screen. This can be done by either textbox or textarea.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? Did you try creating a GUI application? Perhaps using some controls?

Comment: Is it a winform or a webpage?

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiline [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [TextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx)  and append the text to it display and use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) to format text.

```
TextBox1 +=  String.Format("{0}\t{1}", Date.NarratedBy, Date.value) + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: i used a text block for this purpose..so can you tell me what code i should write to display the output in the textblock

Comment: You can use textblock2.Text = "Some Text"

Comment: actually i want to show the data which satisfy the condition ..in my application i tried to show the date and narrated by information of the hadith which has serial number 1..so my output should satisfy this condition..

Comment: You can use String.Format, check my updated answer and tell me if you still have problem? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

Comment: if i used this:                                             xmlTextBlock +=  String.Format("{0}\t{1}", Date.NarratedBy, Date.value) + Environment.NewLine;                               then its showing this error:                                    Cannot Implicitly Convert Type String To windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock

Comment: Change xmlTextBlock to xmlTextBlock.Text

Comment: thanks to everyone who helped me to solve my problem very quickly..thanks alot :) :) :)